# Runaway "Bouncy Ball" widget that can't be caught or killed

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I added the Kde Plasma widget "Bouncy Ball" to the desktop. It's all cool and good. But I became bored with it. So I turned OFF gravity (yeah you see where this is going) then turned ON "auto bounce" and cranked that up. So now this blue ball (yeah I changed the color too) is FLYING all over the place.

So I go into the term do a *ps* and *grep* for "ball" and kill it but it just comes back. I can't catch the ball, anytime I get close it goes flying across the screen.

I think it's reacting to the mouse. I tried locking widgets down, but that doesn't do anything. Any ideas on how to kill this demon ball ????

My setup:
Kubuntu 14.04.5 i386 (amd64 won't load right on the video card but that is a different story).

I have no idea on the version of Plasma or the "Bouncy Ball". If you need that info give me the cmd and I'll get it.

Comment: Haha! Sorry this sounds awful. Dumb question have you tried just uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: Actually when I ps grep for "ball" i'm probably finding my own process. So I am killing my own grep. When I do a ps less then do a find for ball in that I find nothing. So I am not sure which process the ball is.

Comment: I do a widget search and it shows that it is not installed. Since it was a original widget, I don't think that it sees it as something that is installed or can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

GOT IT !!!

```
vi /home/username/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc
```

then edit the line

```
AutoBounceEnabled=true
Gravity=4
```

to something like this

```
AutoBounceEnabled=false
Gravity=88
```

then logged out and back in. Then I was able to grab a hold of it and remove it.

OMG that was so hilar. What a screwup that was.

Comment: Widgets are held as **Applets** inside **Containments** inside the "plasma-desktop-appletsrc" file. If you have troubles with a widget remove the lines under **[Containments][n][Applets][nn]** and that will remove the widget from the screen.